# Trying to modify keys to left and right arrow keys but doesn't work

Tags: karabiner

I have this Json file and it does not apply to the left_arrow key. But it is mapped with something else.

How can I find my keyboard key to find what is which 'key_code'?

```
{
  "title": "For Korean PC Keyboard",
  "rules": [
    {
        "description": "Change Kor/Eng key to command+space",
        "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "lang1"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "left_arrow",
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
        "description": "Change Hanja key to option+return",
        "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "lang2"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "right_arrow",
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve as your descriptions (space … return) don't show up later on.
But generally, you only have *ONE* "key_code" per "to":-expression, so your ","s (commata) therein are superfluous and messing up the script from the start. *(Delete them!)*